# passing ejs array to javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ejs

How do I pass an ejs array in a javascript function?

```
function validate(array) {
alert("Here");
var ok = false;

var emailva = document.getElementById("email").value;
var passva = document.getElementById("password").value;  

  return ok;

 }
```

Im passing my ejs array named as `items` to it something like this

```
<form role="form" action="/index-loggedin" method="post" onsubmit=" return validate("<%= items %>")" >
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your function is located on the server. And you want to pass it a array from a html page (written with EJS).
The only way to send an array from an HTML Page to a server is as a string thanks to JSON format.
Hence, I advice you to send your array as `JSON.stringify(array)`